# ListBox not updated via DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, datasource

I have a ListBox which has its DataSource set to a BindingList.

```
BindingList<PairDiff> pairList = new BindingList<PairDiff>();
pairList.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
listBox1.DataSource = pairList;
```

The type of the BindingList implements and raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged` when one of its members is updated.

Still the ListBox does not update it's display when some data in an existing item is changed. Only when an item is changed or removed.

When I debug into the listBox.Items collection, the new data is there. It is just not displayed!

What is displayed in the ListBox is the PairDiffs `ToString` method.

edit:

```
public class PairDiff : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Pair pair;
    public double diff;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void UpdateDiff(double d) // this is called to update the data in the list
    {
        diff = d;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("diff"));
    }

    public override string ToString() // this is displayed in the list
    {
        return pair + " " + diff;
    }
}
```

to update the data in the listbox:

```
    public void UpdateData(Pair pair, double d)
    {
        var pd = pairList.First((x) => x.pair == pair);
        pd.UpdateDiff( d );
    }
```

Comment: Such question needs [MCVE]. As I tested it works properly if you have a correct implementation.

Comment: May be you need to set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`?

Comment: @T.S. is this required or optional? i am not setting it, because i want to display the result from the ToString method.

Comment: Keep in mind `return pair + " " + diff` will display result of `pair.ToString() + " " + diff.ToString()`. What is in `Pair.ToString()`? Can you clearly post what do you see in the listbox list?

Comment: @T.S. the value of pair does never get updated, only diff gets. and this is just a double.

Comment: Check this out. You seem missing binding source https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @T.S. even when i add another BindingSource between the BindingList and the ListBox.DataSource like in the example, nothing gets updated for me.

Comment: I am still not clear what do you actually see in the list box? and I don't understand why you don't want to create `display` property and move the code from `Tostring` there and set `displayMemeber`?

Comment: I am seeing exactly the text from the ToString method of the PairDiff class. if this can be solved in another way with ths display property that's fine too. I will investigate this now.

Comment: ok, i converted the member `diff` to a property and set it as `DisplayMember` of the listBox. This then displays me a list of all 0s in the listBox instead of the output from ToString. But again it is not changing once the data is modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW i finally found the issue and its that typical winforms threading thing:

putting the update of my listbox in a InvokeRequired block solves it:

```
public void UpdateData(Pair pair, double d)
{
        Action action = () =>
        {
            var pd = pairList.First((x) => x.pair == pair);
            pd.UpdateDiff(d);
        };


        if (listBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            listBox1.Invoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Listbox is caching it's values. The easiest solution is to catch the ListChanged-Event and redraw your Listbox in it:

```
private void Items_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    listbox.Invalidate(); //Force the control to redraw when any elements change
}
```

I refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32951574/how-to-update-a-listbox-if-an-element-was-changed-c-sharp).

Comment: thanks, i cant find that ListChanged event on the listbox, but calling that Invalidate() after i update the data, makes the ListBox flicker. still the contents is not updated.

Comment: @oleole The ListChanged Event is on the BindingList not on the ListBox.

Comment: thanks, i found that event, but still the contents in the listbox dont change when listbox.Invalidate() is called. just the listbox flickers.

Comment: @oleole Can you please update your question with more Code? Show your PairDiff Class please and all Code of listbox and BindingList

Comment: @oleole How is it possible to add .ToString()-Method to Listbox? I think you missunderstand sth. here. Explain me how you add .ToString(); to your Listbox. I think i can build a solution for you then ;)

Comment: ToString is not on the listbox. It is in the PairDiff class which the type of the BindingList which is the DataSource of the listbox.

Comment: @oleole Does the problem occur if you change the diff value via your Update Method? Or just if you change some value on the Pair object inside your PairDiff? I build a own small project where the first part run without any trouble.

Comment: it does always occur, no matter how i update the value of `diff`. It seems the listbox only displays the initial value from when it was filled, but never updates it.

Comment: @oleole you do sth. wrong which i can't figure out based on your question. Can you Share Project via github?

Comment: no sorry, it's a workproject that i'm not allowed to share.